# Copy conditional formatting from one cell to another using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Can I copy conditional formatting from one cell to another using VBA?

I'm imagining something like:

```
Sheets("A").Range("A1:A10").ConditionalFormatting = Sheets("B").Range("B1").ConditionalFormatting
```

Comment: there is not a specfic paste option for conditional formats, however there is a merge , so as long as the destination cells dont have an unique conditional formatting to the source cells then you can use copy and paste  special with type  "xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats"

Comment: I was going to suggest you use the `FormatConditions.ModifiesApplyToRange` method. That will only work if the Conditional Formatting is on the same sheet though.

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
Sub test()
     Sheets("B").[B1].Copy: Sheets("A").[A1:A10].PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: did not work for me, but using `DisplayFormat` based on the following does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036633/1915920