# Excel - format painter macro?

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I hope to be the last part of a big Excel order form project that I've been working on sporatically for months now.

The scenario at this point is that I have a workbook with two worksheets. I have a blank row (A-X) on Sheet2 that has lots of conditional formatting for each cell. I want to get that conditional formatting information onto Sheet1.

I don't know if this is possible, but this would be the best case scenario. The data on Sheet1 begins on row 83. I want that conditional formatting from Sheet2 applied to every row of data on Sheet1. If I manually use the format painter, it does what I want. But it would be great if, with a macro, it could apply the format painting to each row on Sheet1 until there is a blank row.

Is this possible? The only other solution I can think of is to have a macro apply the format painter to rows 83-10000 or something, since that would cover spreadsheets with the most possible data.

Or maybe there's another/better/easier method that replicates what the format painter does?

Comment: Could it be that this is a duplicate post of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388350/copy-conditional-formatting-from-one-cell-to-another-using-vba

Comment: I saw that one, but that one is just copying from one specific cell or range to another. I want to apply conditional formatting from one range to another range that isn't specific.

Comment: @Robby - `.Copy` has the same functionality regardless of the `Range` you're calling it on.  This is a duplicate of the linked question. If you need to select the ranges, someone can point you to Q&As about that too.

Comment: The copied range will always be consistent: A1:X1. I'm not concerned with that. Where it's pasted will be different because the number of data rows will be different. @Pav below is helping me with that. I'd like it to only paste where there is data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that ultimately worked for me. The project morphed a little bit, so now there's only one worksheet instead of two.

```
Sub CopyCFormat2()
    Range("AC1:AY1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A84:X1000").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Select cell/row on your sheet 2, click format painter and having that selected change your sheet to sheet1. Click on desired column headings, not specific cell but the headings. Formatting will be applied to all cells in those columns. Now just click on your cell range 77/82 (you mentioned two different ones) and holding shift click on cell 1 and remove the formatting. Done.

Alternatively for VBA:

`Sheets("Sheet2").[A1].Copy: Sheets("Sheet1").[A78:A10000].PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`

### EDIT

Sorry if I mislead you, for the manual format painter - when I said the header I meant the columns themselves. You can paste formatting based on single row onto entire column content instead of specific cells, see below:

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. I'm wondering if I could use your first method by using the Record Macro function. Either way, it doesn't seem to work for me, maybe because I don't have column headings. Row 82 is always the row before the data, but it doesn't have headings in it.

How would it identify what headings are?

Your VBA code should work, but I wonder if applying the conditional formatting to potentially thousands of rows needlessly would affect the speed. I'd like it to be able to identify the row where the data stops.

Comment: @Robby If you have a new question the please post a new one. Don't add more and more questions to this post. The essence of this site is to have clear questions and clear answers (which are marked as such). Looking at you profile history it seems that you never marked any post as an answer or even up-voted them. You might want to change that and start showing some appreciation by up-voting and marking posts as answers (unless no one on this site was really every able to help you with any of your clear questions).

Comment: Robby - I have added a graphical example to the answer, have a look. That might actually solve your problem without doing any VBA.

And as @Ralph pointed out, go through your posted questions and when you fin the particular answer helpful click the up-vote. When a particular answer solves your problem you can also accept it as the best answer. This both shows your appreciation for the help and in the future if anyone has similar problem it points him to best solution.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense now. But that won't work in what I'm doing because the cells that I want to paste the formats to start on row 84. And since process is going to be done by many people many times, it kind of needs to be VBA.