# Conditionally formatting per Row without VBA?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an array of data that I want to conditionally format *per row*.

The result I need:

[image]

(highest value in *each row* marked in red)

Not like this:

[image]

(highest values *overall* marked in red - notice e.g. the values for row "C")

I have managed this by writing a simple macro, which basically copies conditional formatting for each row (if you are interested, I found this here: [Copy conditional formatting from one cell to another using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388350/copy-conditional-formatting-from-one-cell-to-another-using-vba))

Now, I was wondering, would I be able to achieve the same but just somehow changing formula in conditional formating and/or "Applies to" range.

As I said, the problem itself is solved, but I'm just curious.

Comment: "changing formula in conditional formating": What formula? As far as I see there is not a formula rule used but one color scale rule in case 2 (not like this) and three color scale rules in case 1 (needed result).

Comment: @AxelRichter - both cases are 3-color formula; case 1 is "per row", made manually/with VBA, case 2 is for all 3 rows together, by indicating the whole range (B2:T4); the question was: can you achieve result as from case 1, using the option "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", maybe together with correctly setting "Applies to" range

Comment: "the question was: can you achieve result as from case 1, using the option "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"": No that was not in your question until now. But this is to answer: No it is not possible. It would be possible determining 3 different plain colors by formulas but not the different scaled colors as applied using the `Color Scales` CF.

Comment: @AxelRichter - thank you. I seem to have "flopped" with this question. Will try to improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

yes you change the formula and/or the range for a cfr in vba.